# Is there a way to hide the Google Cardboard SDK's transition view on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am using the Cardboard SDK for iOS to display VR videos within an app, and I am trying to use a custom instruction view to tell the user to put their phone into the Cardboard viewer. As it stands right now no matter what I do the SDK's built in instructional transition view pops up on top of everything. In the Android SDK you can hide the transition view via the `setTransitionViewEnabled(<BOOL>)` method, but I can't find anything comparable on the iOS side. Has anyone been able to do this on iOS?

To add some more information, here is how I'm setting the video view up:

```
let videoView = GVRVideoView()
videoView.delegate = self
videoView.enableFullscreenButton = true
videoView.enableCardboardButton = true
videoView.enableTouchTracking = true

UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: VRDownloadManager.shared.getFilePath(itemURL!))
videoView.loadFromUrl(url)
self.view.addSubview(videoView)
videoView.displayMode = .FullscreenVR
videoView.resume()
```

Comment: which view you want to hide, have you tried with view.hidden property?

Comment: @idindu - The problem is that it's a view within the SDK that isn't exposed as far as I can find, so there's no way I can set it to hidden or anything outside of looping through the whole view hierarchy (which is definitely not a clean way of doing it).

Comment: You can enumerate through its subview and find the one which is a transition view and remove or hide but you need to identify it first.

Comment: Try `videoView.hidesTransitionView = true`.

Answer (score 0):

On the iOS SDK there is a boolean property called `hidesTransitionView` which is defined as:

> Hides the transition view when entering VR mode.

If you set this to true, it should work.

So the code would be:

```
let videoView = GVRVideoView()
videoView.delegate = self
videoView.enableFullscreenButton = true
videoView.enableCardboardButton = true
videoView.enableTouchTracking = true
videoView.hidesTransitionView = true
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/reference/interface_g_v_r_widget_view.html#a4caa081eedcb807d5b5555d8b4f7b777